# How to iterate thorough all items in a structure?

Tags: c, struct, structure

I have for example this format of the structure

```
typedef struct{
  tMY_STRUCT2 my_struct2;
  u16 item1;
  u8 item2[20];      
  u32 item3;
}tMY_STRUCT;
```

**How can I get through the structure?**
Because of **alignment** its not so easy and I cant just calc the offset from begin the structure with **SIZEOF(item)**.

Is there any way?

**Reason:** I need to initiate large structure, there are some conditions for that, so I need to make it within a FOR cycle.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 5):

Don't do this.  The point of a structure is you *can't* handle its data items uniformly.  Structure is to heterogeneous data as array is to homogeneous.

Init each field one at a time in the code or init the whole struct to zero.  Those are the only good practice options.  Alignment in particular will depend on machine architecture, compiler etc. so an approach that uses this will likely break if you make seemingly trivial changes to your code, such as reordering the fields in the declaration, or run on a different OS or compile somewhere else.

Options:

```
memset(mystruct, 0, sizeof(mystruct));
```

or (I think this is C99)  `mystruct_t foo = {0};`

Or just init each field.

Comment: Memset for all structure is not good enough for me, as I said my Init is more difficult than that solution. In my case is defined length of each item(before alignment) in special array. So I have to make function for serialize this strukture to byte array and than use this array for my init cycle.

Comment: 550 items, for each field test some conditions and than init?

Comment: Why on earth do you have 550 items in a structure?  Are you *sure* you shouldn't be using an array?

Comment: In fact I would go so far as to say - if you *can* init these with any uniformity, *without* having to do different logic on each item, then you can and should be using an array pretty much by the defining property of an array.

Comment: There are many level. With array is very difficult to folow this levels. You have to use some offsets, etc. Next advantage I can define small structure once and use it many times in a big structure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand how a for loop is going to help you here... however there is no nice way to iterate through a structure.

You could set up a structure of pointers to the objects in your struct and then skip through that by sizeof( ptr ) but that would be horrible and your co-workers will lynch you.